# Magento 2: modify the appearance of tabs

Tags: magento2

I used to be able to add **rounded corners** to the **tabs** in the **product view** page in **1.8.1**. Now in Magento 2.2 I don't even know where are the files that need to be modified. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks.
Here was the code I used in the css in 1.8.1

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
```

I actually accomplished this by modifying the file:
/lib/web/css/source/lib/_sections.less
I added the following lines and it worked (I am not a programmer, sorry):

```
> .item.title {
            > .switch {
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
                border-top-left-radius: 15px;
                border-top-right-radius: 15px;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying css is not difficult in magento 2. You can simply overwrite catalog_product_view.xml in your custom theme. Then add your custom css file in xml.
Add css for details and reviews tab like this:-

```
#tab-label-product.info.description-title   //Details tab
{
   // add your style here
}
#tab-label-reviews-title   //Reviews tab
{
   // add your style here
}
```

Refer below link to know how to overwrite layout xml file in your custom theme:-
https://www.webdux.com/magento-2-create-a-theme-extending-file-or-override-a-layout-820.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't follow your suggestion but managed to accomplish it by modifying the file: public_html/lib/web/css/source/lib/_sections.less